# Is there a way to track the current context without updating at regular time intervals?

Tags: dynamic

I would like to create a dynamically updated value of the current `$Context`. The problem I have encountered is that the expression

```
Dynamic[$Context]
```

produces an output that updates only when `Begin` expression is evaluated but not `End`. For example, if I evaluate the above expression in a fresh Kernel, I obtain

```
Global`
```

as expected. Then, after evaluation of

```
Begin["lalala`"]
```

the dynamic output correctly switches to

```
lalala`
```

but after evaluation of

```
End[]
```

the dynamic output remains

```
lalala`
```

Of course, I could just use manual update at regular times intervals via `Refresh`:

```
Dynamic[Refresh[$Context, UpdateInterval -> 0.1]]
```

but it would cause the kernel to check `$Context` every 100 milliseconds while the output is visible, which I find inefficient.

I have tried introducing an auxiliary symbol:

```
x := $Context;
Dynamic[x]
```

but to no avail.

Is there a way to make `Dynamic` catch this change of `$Context`?

**P.S.**

Just in case:

```
$Version
(*Returns: 11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)*)
```

**EDIT1**

Just in case someone is interested in the question, here is my "research rabbit":

Cell 1:

```
ClearAll[x];
x /; $Context === "Global`" := 1;
x /; $Context === "a`" := 2;
x /; $Context === "b`" := 3
```

Cell 2:

```
Row[
 {
  Dynamic[Refresh[$Context, UpdateInterval -> 0.01]],
  Dynamic[$Context],
  Dynamic[x]
 },
 "|"
 ]
```

Cell 3:

```
Pause[1]; Begin["a`"];
Pause[1]; Begin["b`"]
Pause[1]; End[];
Pause[1]; End[];
```

**EDIT2**

Funny, but calling Documentation Center (directly or via F1) refreshes the dynamic. I really love *Mathematica*! There is so much to investigate.

**EDIT3**

@Jason B. proposed brutal force as a solution:

```
Unprotect[End, EndPackage];

End[] := Block[{$inMsg = True, new, result},
   result = End[];
   new = $Context;
   $Context = "`";
   $Context = new;
   result
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg]

EndPackage[] := Block[{$inMsg = True, new, result},
   result = EndPackage[];
   new = $Context;
   $Context = "`";
   $Context = new;
   result
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg]

Protect[End, EndPackage];
```

the essence of which is to hack `End` and the friend to manually and explicitly assign a value to `$Context`.

Comment: It seems entirely too hacky a solution for me to put in an answer, but if you evaluate [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/2rqStSbR) then your `Dynamic` works as expected.

Comment: I would report that issue first.

Comment: Same behavior in 13.2.0 : Dynamic[$Context] does not update after End or EndPackage